# Set only one optional parameter of a JS function with ES6

Tags: javascript, function, ecmascript-6

In python, we can do:

```
func(a, b=1, c=2)
```

And then call it like that

```
func(8, c=5)
```

With ES6, we can declare it in the same way :

```
func(a, b=1, c=2)
```

But how to set c without setting b to undefined ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create a function that accepts an object, and get the parameters using destructuring. Now you can pass the parameters in any order you wish:

```js
function fn({ a, b = 1, c = 2 }) {
  console.log({ a, b, c })
}

fn({ a: 8, c: 5 })
```

Comment: Ok, so I guess there is no way to do this without going through an object?

Comment: Not that I know off.